# Dynamically adding preloads in Ecto query

Tags: join, ecto, preload

I have a table `A` and `has_one` tables `B` and `C`.

I am doing a query on `A`, but, depending on columns requested, I want the possibility to `join` and `preload` columns from `B` and/or `C`.

For joins, I think it's rather easy, they can be dynamically chained to the query before invoking `Repo.all`. But what to do with the preload? Depending on whether I need tables `B` and `C` in the query, preload should have different arguments, or shouldn't be there at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i propose is to create the preload list dynamically and pass it to the preload().

The structure of request sent to the backend for me is like this:

```
{
    limit: 10,
    offset: 0,
    preloads: {"research_status": null, "assets": null, "notes": null, "job_applications": {"job_position": null, "status": null, "discarded_reason_var": null}}
}
```

In the above request example, the User entity has associations with research_status, assets, notes and job_applications. The job_applications have again associations with job_position, status and notes.

I have created a helper function to parse the 'preloads' in args, (you can do it wherever you want, im doing it in controller):

```
def parse_query_preloads(%{"preloads" => preloads} = params) do
        preloads
        |> Jason.decode!()
        |> build_preloads()
        |> (&Map.put(params, "preloads", &1)).()
      end

def parse_query_preloads(params), do: params

defp build_preloads(preload_map),
        do:
          preload_map
          |> Enum.map(fn
            {preload, sub_preload} when not is_nil(sub_preload) and is_map(sub_preload) ->
              [{preload |> String.to_atom(), build_preloads(sub_preload)}]
              |> Enum.into([])

            {preload, nil} ->
              preload
              |> String.to_atom()
          end)
```

Parsing the params, like this, in controller:

```
params =
      params
      |> format_pagination()
      |> parse_query_preloads()
```

And finally in my query, i would simply take the `params["preloads"]` and use them in preload function.

```
User
|> preload(^params["preloads"])
|> limit(^params["limit"])
|> offset(^params["offset"])
|> Repo.all()
```

This would make the preloads in the query dynamic. I hope this solves your problem, let me know for errors/improvements.